# How does Visual Studio process the App_Code folder specially?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vs-web-site-project, app-code

How does Visual Studio process the App_Code folder when a change is made or detected in it? Not IIS or ASP.NET.

I want to gain a better understanding of why Visual Studio freezes for long periods of time whenever I save a code file inside a large App_Code folder of a website project. Alternatively, I could ask: why does Visual Studio not exhibit these same freezes when processing a file inside a class library that is equally large?

Ideally I would like to see official documentation cited from Microsoft of the issue at hand of processing the App_Code folder in Visual Studio and what happens that differs from processing a class library for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The App_Code folder is not explicitly marked as containing files
>   written in any one programming language. Instead, the ASP.NET infers
>   which compiler to invoke for the App_Code folder based on the files it
>   contains. If the App_Code folder contains .vb files, ASP.NET uses the
>   Visual Basic compiler; if it contains .cs files, ASP.NET uses the C#
>   compiler, and so on.
>
> If the App_Code folder contains only files where the programming
>   language is ambiguous, such as a .wsdl file, ASP.NET uses the default
>   compiler for Web applications, as established in the compilation
>   element of the application Web.config file or the machine-level
>   Web.config file. Compilers are named build providers and a build
>   provider is specified for each file extension in an **extension**
>   element.

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23.aspx) here.

Comment: This is a helpful answer. In summary the App_Code folder is dynamically compiled in various ways upon small changes, and this leads to differences in performance compared to explicitly compiled projects like class libraries.

Answer (score 1):

It recompiles all code in this folder in a separate assembly, then reference this assembly in your project.

You should be aware that a double reference could occur if you include these files as compilable in your project. In this latter case, the files are at the same time compiles in a separate assembly (with a temp name) which is referenced, and also compiled in the bin folder. This is the start of the horror show ...

Answer (score 0):

These performance notes about the App_Code folder are slightly dated but likely still apply to the project type:

> 2) Keep the number of files in your /app_code directory small.  If you
>   end up having a lot of class files within this directory, I'd
>   recommend you instead add a separate class library project to your VS
>   solution and move these classes within that instead since class
>   library projects compile faster than compiling classes in the
>   /app_code directory.  This isn't usually an issue if you just have a
>   small number of files in /app_code, but if you have lots of
>   directories or dozens of files you will be able to get speed
>   improvements by moving these files into a separate class library
>   project and then reference that project from your web-site instead. 
>   One other thing to be aware of is that whenever you switch from source
>   to design-view within the VS HTML designer, the designer causes the
>   /app_code directory to be compiled before the designer surface loads. 
>   The reason for this is so that you can host controls defined within
>   /app_code in the designer.  If you don't have an /app_code directory,
>   or only have a few files defined within it, the page designer will be
>   able to load much quicker (since it doesn't need to perform a big
>   compilation first).

-- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/09/22/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Optimizing-ASP.NET-2.0-Web-Project-Build-Performance-with-VS-2005.aspx